# binwidth for a histogram in R

Tags: r

This is my program so far. I need to ask the user to input their own bindwidth next and i can't figure out how to do it.

```
file.name <- readline('Please enter name and file location: ')
has.header <- readline('Does your data file contain a header (Y/N)? ')

if (has.header == 'Y')
{
  file.df <- read.table( file = file.name, sep=',', header = TRUE)
}else
{
  file.df <- read.table ( file = file.name, sep=',', header = FALSE)
}
cat('\n')
print(file.df)
cat('\n')

#Histogram 
print(head(file.df))
column <- as.numeric(readline('What column do you want to graph (enter           number)? '))
print(hist(file.df[ ,column]))

#New bin width
binsize <- readline("Enter a new bin width for your graph: ")
```

Comment: fixed code formatting

Answer (score 1):

```
binsize <- as.integer(readline("Enter a new bin width for your graph: "))
xt <- readline("Enter x axis title: ")
yt <- readline("Enter y axis title: ")

binwidth <- as.integer(nrow(file.df)/binsize))

hist(file.df[, column], breaks = binwidth, xlab = xt, ylab = yt)
```

Comment: Trying to make it without ggplot, is there no way of doing that?

Comment: Totally; fixed. That said, perhaps there's a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: #New bin width
print(head(file.df))
binsize <- readline("Enter a new bin width for your graph")

hist(file.df[, column], breaks = as.integer(nrow(file.df)/binsize))

Error im getting:

> hist(file.df[, column], breaks = as.integer(nrow(file.df)/binsize))
Error in nrow(file.df)/binsize : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: It seems like binsize is not an integer. Try replacing `binsize <- readline("Enter a new bin width for your graph")` with `binsize <- as.integer(readline("Enter a new bin width for your graph"))`

Comment: another silly question, sorry. how do I ask the user for a title and x and y axis names

Comment: See edit. Consult https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html if you have further questions about `hist()` parameters